# Shell to powershell

Tags: powershell, sorting

I need to check if I have duplicate passwords from multiple password lists.
I made this command under linux which works `sort -u -o dict_sorted_uniqued.txt *` but I don't have enough space on the hard drive for it to go all the way.
I cannot find the command to do the same thing with powershell under windows (there I have enough storage to do the manipulation)
I started with a cmd line like this: `Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Sort-Object -Unique -Out-File test.txt` but it's not good.

Which powershell command should I use?

Update 
Yes of course.
I have these files there

```
Top2Billion-probable-v2.txt
Top109Million-probable-v2.txt
Top12Thousand-probable-v2.txt
Top1575-probable2.txt
Top1pt6Million-probable-v2.txt
Top207-probable-v2.txt
Top29Million-probable-v2.txt
Top2Billion-probable-v2.txt
Top304Thousand-probable-v2.txt
Top353Million-probable-v2.txt
Rockyou.txt
```

i want to take all unique password and put them in a new file

Comment: Could you show a sample input and expected output. Difficult to see what you are doing here.

Comment: i have update the original post

Comment: Sort-object doesn't have an -out-file parameter.  But you can pipe it to out-file.

Comment: Finally, i try this command `Get-Content * | Sort | Get-Unique > test123.txt` and i think it's the good one. In progress...

Comment: How big are those files? If the data doesn't fit into memory, consider using a database instead.

Comment: the bigest make 27go so it's too big i have only 32 go of memory. Powershell closes before finishing the operation. I'm going to do this in other way. don't know how can i use a databse, maybe i'm going to concatenate files and do somethings with awk